# Javascript array iteration

Tags: javascript, json, sessionstorage

I have a JavaScript array in `sessionStorage` and when I do a `sessionStorage.getitem('states')`, I am getting like this:

```
"{
    "TamilNadu": [
        "Chennai", 
        "Trichy", 
        "Madurai"
    ],
    "Andhra": [
        "Hyderabad",
        "Vizhag"
    ],
    "Karnataka": [
        "Bangalore",
        "Mysore",
        "Darwad"
    ],
    "Maharashtra": [
        "Mumbai",
        "Pune"
    ]
}"
```

Now my requirement is to get the state name from the city name.
For example if I pass `"Mumbai"` to a function as a parameter, that function should read this `sessionstorage` value and return me `"Maharashtra"`.

Could you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Hello Manwal, i am pretty much a newbie to javascript programming. I have just started learning. So didnt try much as i was not sure what to do.

Comment: nit-pick: you don't have an array, you have a JSON string, that -when parsed- will yield an _object_. An object is not the same as an array

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers in a very short time. I am very much grateful. I tried the code by "Pavel" and "belhyk" and it is giving me the results as expected. Just one question. In future the json string grows a lot and contains so much of data, any of these answers given below should work, isnt it?

Comment: All answers will work. But if your json will grow, I suggest to look at performance (see my answer bellow). Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
sessionStorage.getitem('states')
```

returns a string. You must parse it with:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getitem('states'))
```

And next access object attributes with square brackets or a dot:

```
for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && obj[attr][0] == 'Mumbai') {
        return attr;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers in a very short time. I am very much grateful. I tried the code and it is giving me the results as expected. Just one question. In future the json string grows a lot and contains so much of data, any of these answers given below should work, isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getStateByCityName (cityName) {
    var states = {};
    try {
        states = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getitem('states'));
    } catch (e) {
    }
    for (var state in states) {
        for (var i = 0; i < states[state].length; i ++) {
            if (states[state][i] == cityName)
                return state;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How can you iterate over a string?

Comment: You must do a JSON.parse

Comment: I have added parsing of a string

Comment: Adding a try...catch without really handling the error doesn't really do much good in my opinion. You just really "hide" the error, which means you cannot differentiate between when the states data could not be read for some reason and when you asked for a cityName not present.

Comment: try...catch for "JSON.parse" is a minimal handling for this function

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers in a very short time. I am very much grateful. I tried the code and it is giving me the results as expected. Just one question. In future the json string grows a lot and contains so much of data, any of these answers given below should work, isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use `if (states[state].indexOf(cityName) !== -1)`

```
getStateByCityName(cityName) {
    var statesRaw = sessionStorage.getitem('states');
    var states = JSON.parse(statesRaw);
    for (var state in states) {
        if (states[state].indexOf(cityName) !== -1) {
            return state;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or in EcmaScript 5 loop style :))

```
getStateByCityName(cityName) {
    var statesRaw = sessionStorage.getitem('states');
    var states = JSON.parse(statesRaw);

    Object.keys(states).forEach(function(state) {
        if (states[state].indexOf(cityName) !== -1) {
            return state;
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

---

There are many ways (see other answers too) so let's take a look at performance.

First to iterate through your object
http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in-with-closure/3

In my browser fastest case was `Object.keys for loop`, so

```
getStateByCityName(cityName) {
    var statesRaw = sessionStorage.getitem('states');
    var states = JSON.parse(statesRaw);
    var states_keys = Object.keys(states);

    for (var i = 0, l = states_keys.length; i < l; i++) {
          // check if city exists
    }
    return false;
}
```

Next we need to check if city exists in that state. I see two ways to do it:
1) as others suggested iterate with `for` loop
2) mine suggested `.indexOf()`

http://jsperf.com/js-for-loop-vs-array-indexof/2
in my browser `indexOf()` got better results, so final function

```
getStateByCityName(cityName) {
    var statesRaw = sessionStorage.getitem('states');
    var states = JSON.parse(statesRaw);
    var states_keys = Object.keys(states);

    for (var i = 0, l = states_keys.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (states[states_keys[i]].indexOf(cityName) !== -1) {
            return states_keys[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And as some one suggested use `try/catch`

```
getStateByCityName(cityName) {
    var states = {};
    try {
        states = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getitem('states'));
    } catch (e) {
    }
    var states_keys = Object.keys(states);

    for (var i = 0, l = states_keys.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (states[states_keys[i]].indexOf(cityName) !== -1) {
            return states_keys[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arūnas Smaliukas for giving me this whole bunch of information on this. I will follow these.

Answer (score 0):

That should work but can't test it:

```
function (arrayTarget, itemToSearch){
    for (x in arrayTarget) {
        for(y in arrayTarget[x])
            if(itemToSearch == arrayTarget[x][y])
                 return x;   
    }
}
```